# jQuery UI Datepicker enable specific days in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi i can't seem to figure out how to incorporate my working days array into the getDay() function in jquery-ui datepicker script. I would like to enable the days in wd array, how can i do so?

```
var work_day= <?php echo json_encode($workingdays ); ?>;
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        for (i = 0; i < work_day.length; i++) {
            return [day==work_day[i]];
        }
        }
});
```

Comment: hope this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/4/

Comment: ok ive got it thank you @BeingSunny